# Spring Error while using filter and wrapper

Tags: spring, filter, wrapper

I'm using the filter to check user rights.
Problem in comparing session value to param value is occurred and resolution load is applied using wrapper.

However, the following error message came out.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> loginInfo = (List<Map<String,Object>>)session.getAttribute("loginSession");


            if loginInfo.get(0).get("user_type").equals("1") || loginInfo.get(0).get("user_type").equals("2")) 
            {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);

            }
            else 
            {
                RereadableRequestWrapper wrapperRequest = new RereadableRequestWrapper(request);

                String requestBody= IOUtils.toString(wrapperRequest.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

                Enumeration<String> reqeustNames = request.getParameterNames();
                if(requestBody == null) {
                }

                Map<String,Object> param_map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(requestBody, HashMap.class);

                String userId_param = String.valueOf(param_map.get("customer_id"));
                System.out.println(userId_param);
                if( userId_param == null || userId_param.isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("error, customer_id  error");
                }

                if (!loginInfo.get(0).get("customer_id").equals(userId_param)) 
                {
                    logger.debug("error, customer_id  error");
                }
                chain.doFilter(wrapperRequest, res);
            }
```

/////////////////////////
here is my wrapper Code. 
    private boolean parametersParsed = false;

```
    private final Charset encoding;
    private final byte[] rawData;
    private final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ByteChunk tmpName = new ByteChunk();
    ByteChunk tmpValue = new ByteChunk();

    private class ByteChunk {

        private byte[] buff;
        private int start = 0;
        private int end;

        public void setByteChunk(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
            buff = b;
            start = off;
            end = start + len;
        }

        public byte[] getBytes() {
            return buff;
        }

        public int getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public int getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        public void recycle() {
            buff = null;
            start = 0;
            end = 0;
        }
    }

public RereadableRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);

    String characterEncoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(characterEncoding)) {
        characterEncoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    }
    this.encoding = Charset.forName(characterEncoding);

    // Convert InputStream data to byte array and store it to this wrapper instance.
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        this.rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.rawData);
    ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    return servletInputStream;
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream(), this.encoding));
}

@Override
public ServletRequest getRequest() {
    return super.getRequest();
}

@Override
public String getParameter(String name) {
    if (!parametersParsed) {
        parseParameters();
    }
    ArrayList<String> values = this.parameters.get(name);
    if (values == null || values.size() == 0)
        return null;
    return values.get(0);
}

public HashMap<String, String[]> getParameters() {
    if (!parametersParsed) {
        parseParameters();
    }
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>(this.parameters.size() * 2);
    for (String name : this.parameters.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> values = this.parameters.get(name);
        map.put(name, values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));
    }
    return map;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Map getParameterMap() {
    return getParameters();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Enumeration getParameterNames() {
    return new Enumeration<String>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private String[] arr = (String[])(getParameterMap().keySet().toArray(new String[0]));
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return index < arr.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String nextElement() {
            return arr[index++];
        }
    };
}

@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
    if (!parametersParsed) {
        parseParameters();
    }
    ArrayList<String> values = this.parameters.get(name);
    String[] arr = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
    if (arr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return arr;
}

private void parseParameters() {
    parametersParsed = true;

    if (!("application/x-www-form-urlencoded".equalsIgnoreCase(super.getContentType()))) {
        return;
    }

    int pos = 0;
    int end = this.rawData.length;

    while (pos < end) {
        int nameStart = pos;
        int nameEnd = -1;
        int valueStart = -1;
        int valueEnd = -1;

        boolean parsingName = true;
        boolean decodeName = false;
        boolean decodeValue = false;
        boolean parameterComplete = false;

        do {
            switch (this.rawData[pos]) {
                case '=':
                    if (parsingName) {
                        // Name finished. Value starts from next character
                        nameEnd = pos;
                        parsingName = false;
                        valueStart = ++pos;
                    } else {
                        // Equals character in value
                        pos++;
                    }
                    break;
                case '&':
                    if (parsingName) {
                        // Name finished. No value.
                        nameEnd = pos;
                    } else {
                        // Value finished
                        valueEnd = pos;
                    }
                    parameterComplete = true;
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case '%':
                case '+':
                    // Decoding required
                    if (parsingName) {
                        decodeName = true;
                    } else {
                        decodeValue = true;
                    }
                    pos++;
                    break;
                default:
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!parameterComplete && pos < end);

        if (pos == end) {
            if (nameEnd == -1) {
                nameEnd = pos;
            } else if (valueStart > -1 && valueEnd == -1) {
                valueEnd = pos;
            }
        }

        if (nameEnd <= nameStart) {
            continue;
            // ignore invalid chunk
        }

        tmpName.setByteChunk(this.rawData, nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart);
        if (valueStart >= 0) {
            tmpValue.setByteChunk(this.rawData, valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart);
        } else {
            tmpValue.setByteChunk(this.rawData, 0, 0);
        }

        try {
            String name;
            String value;

            if (decodeName) {
                name = new String(URLCodec.decodeUrl(Arrays.copyOfRange(tmpName.getBytes(), tmpName.getStart(), tmpName.getEnd())), this.encoding);
            } else {
                name = new String(tmpName.getBytes(), tmpName.getStart(), tmpName.getEnd() - tmpName.getStart(), this.encoding);
            }

            if (valueStart >= 0) {
                if (decodeValue) {
                    value = new String(URLCodec.decodeUrl(Arrays.copyOfRange(tmpValue.getBytes(), tmpValue.getStart(), tmpValue.getEnd())), this.encoding);
                } else {
                    value = new String(tmpValue.getBytes(), tmpValue.getStart(), tmpValue.getEnd() - tmpValue.getStart(), this.encoding);
                }
            } else {
                value = "";
            }

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
                ArrayList<String> values = this.parameters.get(name);
                if (values == null) {
                    values = new ArrayList<String>(1);
                    this.parameters.put(name, values);
                }
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
                    values.add(value);
                }
            }
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            // ignore invalid chunk
        }

        tmpName.recycle();
        tmpValue.recycle();
    }
}

  and Error Message is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
```

I Don't know why this problem happened...